# Can Mercurial (Hg) show me what remote a branch or a commit is from?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-log, hg-log

I have a Mercurial (Hg) repository with 2 remotes, let's call them `default` and `upstream`.

I have pulled from both remotes and would like to know which commits/branches came from the remote called `default` and which commits/branches came from the remote called `upstream`. How do I achieve this in Hg?

Ideally I would like to use the `hg log` command much like I use the `git log --describe --all` command which I'm more familiar with.

Is there a *template* for the `hg log` command that is equivalent to `git log --describe`?

*Note: I'm already aware of using `hg out <remote>` to show me what set of commits is not available on the remote I'm interested in, but I was hoping for something a little more visual.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without giant changes in standard HG-workflow (assumed in another extension, [remotenames](https://bitbucket.org/seanfarley/hgremotenames)), in default style, you can add [Remote Branches Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RemoteBranchesExtension) to your Mercurial

Answer (score 1):

> I have pulled from both remotes and would like to know which commits/branches came from the remote called `default` and which commits/branches came from the remote called `upstream`. How do I achieve this in Hg?

In general, you can't.  (But see below, and [Lazy Badger's suggested extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364111/1256452).)

Git doesn't actually do this either.  Nonetheless, you can, as you said:

> ... use the git log --describe --all command ...

This does not tell you *who delivered the commits to you*.  Instead, it tells you *which of your references* is "closest" to the to-be-described commit ("closest" being defined in a vague handwave-y manner).  What Git does, that Mercurial doesn't, is to create, in your repository, specific references—remote-tracking names like `remote1/branch` and `remote2/branch`—that remember which commit was identified by the name `branch` on remote1 and remote2 respectively.

Provided that precisely one of the two remotes *has* those commits in the first place, only one such reference can be "closest".  Git will choose that one, and from that, you can infer who has the commits and who does not.  It fails, or can fail, if both remotes have the commits: you get an arbitrary reference (which may suffice anyway depending on your underlying goal).

Now, you *can* do *something*.  Specifically, the issue in this case is that Mercurial's branch names are global, and commits are permanently glued to the branch on which they were made.  If you connect to remote1 and receive some commits, they have whatever hash ID and branch name they have, and your Mercurial stores them in your repository under that same hash ID and using that same name—and now Mercurial (like Git) forgets the source, because those are now *your* commits.

But you *do* know that whatever commits just came in (if any) came from remote1, not remote2.  Moreover, if any commits *did* come in, they will have increased the local revision ID number (`-r -n tip`).  You can save that new number—or even the entire span—somewhere.  *All* of those commits in that span, "old tip + 1" to "new tip" inclusive, came from remote1.

Repeat this for remote2: any new commits that arrive came from them.

(There is another option, but it's drastic: you can use the Convert extension to *change* the branch names of commits as they come in.  If you do this, though, you are stuck with those commits being on the other branch: you would have to copy, i.e., graft or rebase, the commits to move them to their original branches later, if you want that.  There are additional, and better, extensions, but unlike Convert, they are not distributed with Mercurial.)

Comment: @LazyBadger: what's the other extension? There are several possibilities listed on the [Mercurial wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UsingExtensions#Extensions_provided_by_others), yet curiously, though RemoteBranchesExtension is hosted on that wiki, it's not listed on that page. (Though since none of these are distributed with Mercurial, I'll stick with "you can't, except".)

Comment: I can't name "other" extension now, just because I had it in my THG on physically disabled now drive with a separate OS on it (I moved from XP to W10 on another drive last month), sorry

Comment: Repaired and found - https://bitbucket.org/seanfarley/hgremotenames (but it's "too deep changes for OP")

Comment: @LazyBadger: That looks like a very nice extension, that should become part of core Mercurial (in my perhaps Git-biased opinion :-) ).

Comment: I hope it will **not happen** - `remotenames` is too git-style that it becomes even uncomfortable - this costume looks like a clown dress on Mercurial. Remote Branches **is OK** for 99.99% cases

Comment: I'll prefer and use "special named branch per peer" - cheap, fast, easy, native